# How do I set the our_to_self_delay parameter?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, ln-opening-channels, ln-closing-channels

In Core-Lightning, the default value for `our_to_self_delay` is set to `600`. How do I change this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lightning the `to_self_delay` parameter is influenced by your peer. When a node opens a channel to yours, they advertise the minimum they are going to accept.

On Core-Lightning you can set the minimum value to request from peers with the `watchtime-blocks` option. You can learn more about this option in the `lightningd-config` manpage or at the [online documentation](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightningd-config.5.html). By [default this value is set to `144`](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/5b3746172f06c235892e3b1c5fbef50b9a9d8c68/lightningd/options.c#L827-L828) (1 day).

The value of your own `to_self_delay` will depend on your peer. The maximum value a Core-Lightning node will accept can be modified using the `max-locktime-blocks` option (same manpage as above). By [default this value is set to `2016`](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/5b3746172f06c235892e3b1c5fbef50b9a9d8c68/lightningd/options.c#L830-L832) (2 weeks).

Just to emphasize: the default value for the `our_to_self_delay` on Core-Lightning *is not* `600`. You must have picked this from one of your channels, where your peer requested a minimum `to_self_delay` of `600`. Since this is below the `2016` cap set by default, your Core-Lightning accepted to create a channel with this parameter.

Comment: Thank makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @TasosSidiropoulos you are welcome. Feel free to mark it as accepted if that answers your question.